# Логирование выполнения wget в linux

Tags: linux, логирование, wget

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите каким образом можно сделать логирование использования команды wget в linux?

Где-то на одном сервере я видел такое...

У меня на сервере завелась крыса, которая где-то в php прописала комманду для залива шела через wget. Найти эту строчку кода очень сложно. Закрыть известную дыру в CMS (opencart 2) не моту так как эта уязвимость связана с использованием модуля php для json, а он используется для api ... Более новую версию поставить не могу так как на новую версию не подходят те модули, которые используются на сайте и были сделаны на заказ ...

Короче печаль печальная :(

Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: Что именно вы хотите логировать? Можно мувнуть куда-нибудь wget и написать скрип-обертку, который подменит wget. При вызове он выведет в лог дату, pid, аргументы с которыми его запустили, а затем вызовет со всеми аргументами настоящий wget. Это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Доброго времени суток!
Скажите, а будет ли видно какой пользователь запустил wget и какой клиент (php, php скрипт ...)?

Comment: Если сделать выборку из вывода ps -ef по pid/ppid, то да, подобные данные там будут

Answer (score 0):

Можно мувнуть куда-нибудь `wget` и написать скрип-обертку, который подменит wget. При вызове он выведет в лог дату, pid, аргументы с которыми его запустили, а затем вызовет со всеми аргументами настоящий `wget`

Набросал "на коленке" образец скрипта-обертки (ну, убирать из /usr/bin wget у себя я не стал (и менять PATH тоже не стал), а просто сделал линк на него в ~avp/bin, а скрипт с именем wget сделал в своем HOME)

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/tmp/logfile

echo $$/$PPID `date` $0 $* >> $LOG
ps -ef | grep $PPID  | grep -v grep | grep -v 'ps -ef' >> $LOG
echo  >> $LOG
echo "=================="  >> $LOG
echo  >> $LOG

exec /home/avp/bin/wget $*
```

Это пример запуска (и содержимое `~avp/bin`)

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~$ ./wget shhshs
--2023-09-07 23:30:18--  http://shhshs/
Resolving shhshs (shhshs)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘shhshs’
avp@avp-xubu2:~$ ll bin/w*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 avp avp 13 Sep  6 22:16 bin/wget -> /usr/bin/wget*
avp@avp-xubu2:~$
```

А это содержимое лога после пары запусков

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~$ cat /tmp/logfile 
12950/12929 Thu Sep 7 11:28:05 PM MSK 2023 ./wget jhsjsdj sdjdsk
avp        12929   12907  0 23:25 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
avp        12950   12929  0 23:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./wget jhsjsdj sdjdsk

==================

12964/12929 Thu Sep 7 11:30:18 PM MSK 2023 ./wget shhshs
avp        12929   12907  0 23:25 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
avp        12964   12929  0 23:30 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./wget shhshs

==================

avp@avp-xubu2:~$
```

Понятно, чтобы "спрятать"  настоящий `/usr/bin/wget` на сервере, вам надо быть там рутом